# Is it possible to merge two tables that have some similarities

Tags: python, pandas

I am a new python user and trying to merge the data frames that have one column with similar information.

```
Data 1           Data2
DocID GroupID    DocID ClassID
122     A12      121     A
122     A24      121     B
123     C12      122     C
124     C23      123     C
125     A12      123     D
```

I hope the result will be like this

```
Results
          DocID  121  122  123  124  125
GroupID ClassID
  Null     A      1    0    0    0    0
  Null     B      1    0    0    0    0
  A12      C      0    1    0    0    0
  A24      C      0    1    0    0    0
  C12      C      0    0    1    0    0
  C12      D      0    0    1    0    0
  A12     Null    0    0    0    0    1
```

Actually, I'm thinking about mapping function and remove the Null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `merge` and `get_dummies`

```
df2 = df.merge(df1, on='DocID', how='outer').set_index(['GroupID','ClassID'])

df2 = pd.get_dummies(df2.DocID).sort_index(level=0) 
print (df2)
```

#### Output:

```
                      121    122      123    124    125
GroupID  ClassID                    
    NaN     A          1      0        0      0      0
            B          1      0        0      0      0
    A12    NaN         0      0        0      0      1
            C          0      1        0      0      0 
    A24     C          0      1        0      0      0
    C12     C          0      0        1      0      0
            D          0      0        1      0      0
    C23    NaN         0      0        0      1      0
```

Comment: thank you for your help T_T but, I have a question about the df3. that means I have to create another data frame, haven't I?

Comment: @JennieLim Sorry, It was a typo. Updated. Here `df` and `df1` are your `data1` and `data2` dataframes

Comment: Thank you for your help again, I have adapted with CSV file but the results are different from the normal data frames T-T it added one more column and shown Nan T_T

Comment: i don't know how to upload in stackoverflow ;-;. here is the first error 
"ValueError: You are trying to merge on float64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat". then i solved this problem by defining as the string type then the error be like 
A24     C          0      0        0      0      0
C12     C          0      0        0      0      0
Nan.    Nan.     1.     1.       1.     1.     1

Comment: @JennieLim Can you just paste all the contents of your csv file at [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) and share the link. You have to merge on `DocID` and make sure the dtypes are same for both. It could be the issue with merge that causing the difference.

Comment: u inspired me to become a good programmer, i will practice and try to help others too! thank you so much TwT

Comment: @JennieLim Happy to help and All the best. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'DocID': [122,122,123,124,125], 'GroupID': ['A12','A24', 'C12', 'C23', 'A12']})
data2 = pd.DataFrame({'DocID': [121,121,122,123,123], 'ClassID': ['A','B', 'C', 'C', 'D']})
merged_data = pd.merge(data1, data2, on='DocID', how='outer')
merged_data.set_index(['GroupID', 'ClassID'], inplace=True)
result = pd.get_dummies(merged_data, columns=['DocID'], prefix='', prefix_sep='')
result.sort_values(sorted(result.columns), ascending=False, inplace=True)
result
```